# How can I parse a row's column value passed to a UDF when mapping a column?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this, for the sake of simplicity i'm just showing 2 columns both columns are `string`, but in real life it will have more columns each of different types other than `string`:

| SQLText | TableName |
| --- | --- |
| select * from sourceTable; | NewTable |
| select * from sourceTable1; | NewTable1 |

I also have a custom Function where i want to iterate over the dataframe and get the `sql` and run it to create a table, however I'm not passing each column individually, but rather the whole row:

```
def CreateTables(rowp):
    df = spark.sql(rowp.SQLText)
    #code to create table using rowp.TableName
```

This is my code, I first clean up `SQLText` because it's stored in another table and then I run the UDF on the column:

```
l = l.withColumn("SQLText", F.lit(F.regexp_replace(F.col("SQLText").cast("string"), "[\n\r]", " ")))
nt = l.select(l["*"]).withColumn("TableName",CreateTables(F.struct(*list(l.columns)) )).select("TableName","SQLText")
nt.show(truncate=False)
```

So when I'm running the function, and I try to run the code above, it errors out because instead of parsing the `rowp.SQLText` into its literal value, it passes its type?:

```
Column<'struct(SourceSQL, TableName)[SourceSQL]'>
```

So in the `CreateTables` function, when `spark.sql(rowp.SQLText)` is executed I expect the following:

`df = spark.sql("select * from sourceTable;")`

but instead this is happening, the variable type is literally being sent instead of the variable *value*

`df = spark.sql("Column<'struct(SourceSQL, TableName)[SourceSQL]'>")`

I've tried numerous solutions: `getItem`, `getField`, `get`, `getAs` but no luck yet.

I've also tried using indexes like `rowp[0]` but it just changes the variable type passed to the `spark.sql` function:

```
Column<'struct(SourceSQL, TableName)[0]'>
```

If I try `rowp(0)` it gives me a `Column is not callable` error.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

Here is one way I tested in pyspark 3.2.3

```
rows = df.rdd.collect()
for i in range(len(rows)):
  spark.sql(rows[i][0])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way that doesn’t involve bringing the DF in memory (eg not using collect?)